# Is there anything special about the words used to activate the Winter Soldier?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america, captain-america-civil-war, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In *Captain America: Civil War*, the Winter Soldier is 'activated' with the following phrase:

> Longing. Rusted. Seventeen. Daybreak. Furnace. Nine. Benign.
>   Homecoming. One. Freight car.

What does it mean? Why these special words?

Comment: Kinda party pooper on the title change... I found the original one much more entertaining.

Comment: Sorry. We [hate fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Comment: acceptable cross-site dupe: [What were the magic words used by Zemo and what's it referring to?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/52740/1046)

Comment: Annnd activated now, thanks... I mean "your orders?"

Comment: There are some [short fanfics](http://starkandsnow.tumblr.com/post/145003502401/ready-to-comply-js) out there with explanations. Don't know if there's any "official" significance to the words, though.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg We had to change the number, we don't want to inadvertently activate any Russian sleeper agents among us.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Some are probably meaningless

[According to the writers](http://www.cinemablend.com/m/new/There-Any-Significance-Bucky-Trigger-Words-Civil-War-Here-What-Writers-Say-130827.html):

> They’re rhythmic and enigmatic. I can’t remember if we listened to them in Russian to hear if they sounded suitably intimidating, we must have. Because they were really melodic; I’m not sure we would have gone with them [if they weren’t]. But we wanted ones when you read them on the screen you’d have some reaction to it. Like ‘Duress,’ and ‘Freight Car.’ **It’s really just us coming up with stuff. There’s not a lot of rhyme or reason to it.**

On the other hand, as described in Rogue Jedi's answer, some seem not to be so random.
The writers do say that that some of the words are meant to provoke a reaction.

Comment: I noticed that while translated as 'furnace' the word used was 'stove'.

Answer (score 32):

### Some seem to have meaning. Some don't.

"One," "Nine" and "Seventeen" combine to form 1917, the year Bucky was born.

[image: Bucky museum info]

Bucky "died" by falling off a freight car.

[image: Bucky freight car]

*Homecoming* is the name of [the upcoming Spider-Man movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2250912/), but that's probably a coincidence.

These are trigger words and they are meant to be near-impossible for a non-ally to guess or say unintentionally, so at least some of the others are likely meant to be random, in-universe.

Comment: the writers have said that the "homecoming" bit was ["fairly accidental"](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/52742/1046)

Comment: Google "Correct Horse Battery Staple"

Comment: I bet "Benign" was just because it was the first thing that popped in the writers head after he wrote "Nine"

Comment: I hope you get Populist.

Answer (score 16):

xkcd: [Password Strength](https://xkcd.com/936/)

[image]

This explains why it's in Russian, instead of it being *alpha-numeric ST: TNG mumbo jumbo* that no one could ever possibly remember, but would be easy for a computer to hack due to its short length.

This is why a string of words would be, "near-impossible for a non-ally to guess," and why it's a good "passphrase", and why they are *seemingly* "random" and yet they are not.

Comment: "This explains why it's in English" - well, Russian...

Comment: "would be easy for a computer to hack due to its short length" - except Hydra isn't publicly advertising that the Winter Soldier has a password. No one knows he has an activation code, and the length and randomness of the words is just to ensure he never unintentionally hears the activation phrase.

Comment: I have to agrree with @QuestionMarks here, it's more like the [Wake on LAN magic packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet) than a password.

Comment: @QuestionMarks: Hydra may not want to rely on [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), and may therefore prefer an activation code that remains usable even once people know of its existence.

Answer (score 4):

Not based on any official source, but it would seem that they selected a collection of words that wouldn't be used in a conversational way in order to avoid false activation.

How they came upon this particular series of words, I don't know. They may have had some sort of algorithm that would generate such a "passphrase".

Comment: Obviously, such an algorithm is an anti-MEMM.  (A "MEMM" is a [maximum-entropy Markov model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum-entropy_Markov_model).)

Answer (score -1):

The words are a random assortment to prevent them from coming up in a conversation, like with "Why don't you pass the time by playing a little solitaire?"

There's another aspect that I think most people missed.  Bucky responds by saying, "Ready to comply" - that last word a recurring one in various episodes of Agents of SHIELD when HYDRA brainwashing comes into play.

Comment: Damn, I knew I should have double-checked that quote.